# Java.exe not found on Windows command prompt

Tags: java, windows-7, windows-server-2008

Installed Java 1.7 on Windows Server 2008. In Cygwin I can clearly see that `"which java.exe"` returns c:\Windows\System32\ even running "java -version" returns 1.7. But on Windows command prompt and/or Powershell it complains it is not a recognized internal or external command.

Nor I can see the file in Windows explorer in the above mentioned path. Even after changing folder options in Windows explorer.

The Java version installed is 64-bit on Windows Server 2008. It is a ditto behavior on Window 7 as well.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance for any help.

-RG

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-to-find-where-is-jdk-installed-on-my-windows-machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is because your OS is 64 bits, but your installed version of Java is 32-bits. A 32-bit shell (Cygwin's bash or in my case MSYS' sh) can see and run it, but a 64-bit shell (cmd) cannot.

Comment: Don't they say that their java version is 64 bit?

Comment: The OP stated that its *OS* is 64-bits. But nothing prevents you (or me for that matter...) from installing a 32-bits Java. If you don't extend your CMD path with 32-bit Java folder, CMD will not find it. This is because a plain 32-bits java installation creates a java.exe in c:\Windows\SYSWoW64, that 32-bits applications transparently access as c:\Windows\System32... (a "feature" called File System Redirector[1]). 64-bits applications access the "real" c:\Windows\System32, where no such java.exe exists.

[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Very true, but OP states `The Java version installed is 64-bit on Windows Server 2008. It is a ditto behavior on Window 7 as well.`

Comment: I missed that bit, sorry. Yet, all the symptoms are consistent with the OP having installed a 32-bit Java on its 64-bit OS.
It may help resolve the issue if the OP could determine (using Windows Explorer) whether a java.exe exists in c:\Windows\SYSWoW64.

Comment: Yes. I do see java.exe in c:\windows\syswow64. Is there a option on java.exe that will tell me whether it is 32 or 64 bit. From above explaination from user2195045 it appears that I have 32-bit installed, it is partly because java/com/en/download/chrome.jsp does not give me an option to choose binary. So could it be that I have 32-bit chrome browser which lead java site to redirect me to 32-bit download...

Comment: You can use Cygwin's "file" command, which (unlike MSYS...) will explicitely tell you if a PE executable is 32 or 64 bits (MSYS tells you it's a "Mono/.Net assembly")
You can also start java --version. Oracle's java.exe 64-bit explicitly states so. 32-bit is mute about it.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use cygwin64, or put %JAVA_HOME%\bin at the start of PATH environment variable.Because https://superuser.com/questions/563016/why-is-java-exe-not-visible-from-cygwin-but-is-visible-from-command-prompt

Answer (score 1):

You might have to set your environmental variables to point to your JAVA installation.

http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: I had used Java installer which sets the JAVA_HOME variable plus Java was installed in C:\Windows\System32 which is by default available in %PATH% environment variable. I still don't know why I can't run Java from Windows command prompt. I gave up on that and instead launch java (or .jar programs from Cygwin window.) This behavior I have only seen in Windows Server 2008. The same Java installation on Windows 7 behaves normal. Still open to hear any one's solution.

Comment: @RgGlpj Post what your %PATH% variable is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I needed the answer and didn't find it here so I will provide it for others:

Enter the variable value as the installation path for the Java Development Kit.
If your Java installation directory has a space in its path name, you should use the shortened path name (e.g. C:\Progra~1\Java\jre6) in the environment variable instead.

Icon
Note for Windows users on 64-bit systems

Progra~1 = 'Program Files'
Progra~2 = 'Program Files(x86)'

*Source of answer came from atlassian.*