# How to run built java file with the extension .jar

Tags: java, netbeans

I made a desktop application with Java netbeans, it's a Jframe with some components. I built it and the .jar file created in the dist folder in the project folder. I have already the jre (Java Runtime Environment) installed on my pc. When I try to open the .jar with the jre I got nothing, Nothing appears. What can I do ?

Comment: you sure it don't crashes on the start?

Comment: Go to the command line.  Change directories to where the jar file is type `java -jar {nameOfJar}.jar` - assuming the Java is in the path

Comment: @MadProgrammer how can i do that ? please explain more

Comment: Open a command prompt, `CD` to the location of the jar file and use `java -jar {nameOfJar}.jar` to execute the Jar.  If you're unfamiliar with how to use the command prompt/terminal then I suggest you need to find a better tutorial on the subject...

Comment: @MadProgrammer should I remover the { } ??

java -jar {nameOfJar}.jar  or java -jar nameOfJar.jar

Comment: Yes - sorry, I don't know the name of your jar file so I added a filler

Comment: No Problem, now I tried to execute the .jar file normally (not through using CMD), there is an error message saying (A Java Exception Error) with a title Java Virtual Machine Launcher

Comment: When I try to run through CMD there's Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Comment: @user2266606 Read my answer below (especially the edited to add part)

Answer (score 0):

https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#Exercise_1

The link above will take you to a tutorial.  Jar files are not executable by default.  You need to specify a starting class to make a jar file executable.

If this doesn't work, then make sure you have called `setVisible(true)` on your JFrame.

Edited to add: (author added info)

> When I try to run through CMD there's Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

This means your JRE version does not match your compiler version.  You can confirm with the -version option, then fix your path to use Java from the same place your compiler lives.

Comment: Google search: How do I set my path on Windows?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-to-find-where-is-jdk-installed-on-my-windows-machine