# Java / Executable Jar works with cmd / doesn't work with double-click

Tags: java, executable-jar

OS: Windows 7 x64

IDE: Eclipse [ latest version ]

Eclipse JRE: [ as bellow ]

JDK: 1.7.0_51

JRE: 1.7.0_51_b13 [ came with JDK ]

Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe [ established ]

The executable jar has been created using Eclipse>Export>Executable Jar>...

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Class-Path: .

Main-Class: pfp.beta.Main

The Main class does actually exist inside package specified in manifest file.
I can successfully run the application using CMD with administrative rights, however fail to do so without administrative rights.

I've entered manually a new entry into PATH and it didn't work.

I've used jarfix in order to fix the problem. The fix has shown no result.

I've removed all Java products from the system and installed them clean.

I've checked for old versions and removed those as well.

I've looked up all the threads here on stackoverflow and none of them fixed my problem.

Currently I deploy *.bat file with java -jar NAME_OF_THE_FILE.jar inside the same folder as *.jar file to run the program. I would like to get to the bottom of this issue and run it by double-clicking the icon.

The program executes on double-click, however it is my believe - it doesn't locate the main class to progress further.

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5827164/why-does-my-jar-file-execute-at-cmd-but-not-on-double-click?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333660/java-application-will-run-from-cmd-and-eclipse-but-not-double-click?rq=1

Comment: Both of these posts have been viewed. I really cannot figure out why it does not execute the jar file...