# JAVA_HOME has been set, but java - version cannot be found in command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt

[EDITED]

I have set my JAVA_HOME variable to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\"

and after running javac -version on Command Prompt , i get this:

```
javac 1.7.0_07
```

However when i run java-version , i get this:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>java -version
Error: Failed reading value of registry key:
    Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\C
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
```

To clarify, i have the following files in my C:\Program Files\Java

(1) jdk1.5.0_14  (this file cannot be deleted, as its said to be in use by the system

(2) jdk1.8.0_60

(3) jre1.5.0_14

(4) jre1.8.0_60

May i know how to ensure that all jre and jdk points to the 1.8 version; and also how to get rid of the above mentioned error?

I get this upon echoing %PATH%:

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Users\User\introcs\java\bin;C:\PROGRAM FI
LES\BROADCOM\BROADCOM 802.11 NETWORK ADAPTER;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\NVIDIA CORPO
RATION\PHYSX\COMMON;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\ICLS CLIENT\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\I
NTEL\ICLS CLIENT\;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\WIN
DOWS\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT
 ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C:\PROGRAM FILES\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONE
NTS\IPT;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\DAL;C
:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\INTEL(R) MANAGEMENT ENGINE COMPONENTS\IPT;C:\PROGRAM
 FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SDK\2.0\BIN\X86;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\OPENCL SD
K\2.0\BIN\X64;C:\PROGRAM FILES\SONY\VAIO IMPROVEMENT;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\SONY
\VAIO BIOS DATA TRANSFER UTILITY\;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\SONY\VAIO STARTUP SETTI
NG TOOL;;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\WINDOWS\SYST
EM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Pro
gram Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Ki
ts\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\To
ols\Binn\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementS
tudio\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Serv
er\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\User\introcs\j3d\b
in;C:\Users\User\introcs\bin;C:\Users\User\introcs\java\bin;
```

Comment: post the o/p of `echo %PATH%`

Comment: it seems that, the java installation pointed by the `PATH` environment variable is corrupted.

Comment: echoed and posted in the edited version of my post. ty

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set above path up to bin folder "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin"
for jre you can set "C:\Program Files\Java\ jre1.8.0_60\bin"

Note: put above location to "PATH" system environment variables.
hope this will help.

Comment: do you mean putting this in the system env variables "Path"? i have just added this extra path to the variable "Path" , but the error persists

Answer (score 1):

When you write javac on cmd promt, it is not getting it from `JAVA_HOME`. `JAVA_HOME` variable is usually for programs written in java for finding JVM easily.

What you are searching for is `PATH`. It promt scans the paths and binds executables  than you can use them without giving absolute path.

When you write javac, it gets the javac given by `PATH`.

So in you case `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Users\User\introcs\java\bin;`
must be directing the wrong path, i advice delete them and give the path of the version you desired.

Comment: i am unable to delete the oracle folder as the folder is in use

Comment: mklink /d C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.XXX\bin\ this will create a link of your java directory under this path

Answer (score 1):

Also check your Windows directory (I think it's in Windows/System32) for java*.exe and delete those. They tend to override the manually installed JVM and thus any environment settings you add to your PATH for a JDK or JRE.
After that, add your %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your PATH, start a new command prompt, and you're good to go.

Comment: i dont find any java.exe in my windows/system32