# Android Studio Java Home seems to be invalid Error

Tags: android

> Error:The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid.

I cannot find the Java executable. Tried location: `C:\Users\Ammara\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\bin\java.exe`

Comment: JavaHome should point to the Java installation folder and not for the android one

Answer (score 0):

Please find actual location of where java is installed. Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine)