# While building a simple application using bazel getting error Couldn't find java at '/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java'

Tags: java, c++, bazel, building

[terminal view at the time error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKaUr.png)

I was building a simple app using bazel building tool. But i got the this error
stating that java is not found *(Couldn't find java at '/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java'*). Although i have java installed on my system.
Now, i want to know that in any way can't we let bazel know that java is installed and how to look for that?

Comment: Find where your java is installed - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine

Comment: How to make bazel know that it is installed in a particular directory and not where it is looking for.

Comment: What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` say?

Comment: it says /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_74

Comment: Well, does that folder contain `bin/java`?

Comment: Well the folder /usr/lib/java/ itself does not exist.

Comment: You need to fix JAVA_HOME to point at your java installation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now my problem can be fixed

Comment: I think I need to change the value of the environment variable JAVA_HOME. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

in */etc/bash.bashrc* add

```
export JAVA_HOME='position_where_java_installted'
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```