# How add context menu item to Windows Explorer for folders different than exe

Tags: java, jar, path, registry, parameter-passing

I successfully added an item to the context menu of folders (that's the easy part) but my program is jar extension when I try to open it via context menu error appears: This program will not work on your computer or something like this, so I tried in command value write this:

```
Java -jar path.jar "%1"
```

Results were the same. My workaround is bat file to open jar file xD but there are two problems:

1. An unpleasant black cmd window pops up every time
2. Paths with spaces don't work (the program is given null?)

How to do it so I can rid of this bat?

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is much more of a Windows than a java problem, so more of a generic approach:

Don't try to directly run your java code. Instead: write a script (for example using *PowerShell* that gets called).

And within **that** script, you could be doing things such as:

- [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine) the windows machine for a java installation
- checking/translating relative paths to "correct" absolute values
- to then, finally invoke *some* java.exe with correct parameters

Comment: So PowerShell learning here I go xD, thanks for guiding, shame there isn't a simpler way. I will post complete ps1 script

Comment: @KacperLechowicz I am not saying that you *must* do it that way. I just anticipate that, in the end, this is a more reliable approach, costing you less time overall ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple code :

```
param (
[string]$p1
)
function Find-JavaExe {
[CmdletBinding()]
param ()

$JavaExeSuffix = 'bin\java.exe'

if ($env:JAVAHOME -eq $null) {
    Write-Debug "`$env:JAVAHOME doesn't exist, going to look elsewhere"
}
else {
    $JavaHomeBasedPath = Join-Path $env:JAVAHOME $JavaExeSuffix
    Write-Debug "Testing for $JavaHomeBasedPath, based on `$env:JAVAHOME"
    if (Test-Path $JavaHomeBasedPath) {
        Write-Debug "Found $JavaExePath"
        return $JavaExePath
    }
}

$RegistrySearchPaths = @('HKLM:\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\', 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\')
$JavaExePath = $RegistrySearchPaths |
    where { Test-Path $_ } |
    % {
        $CurrentVersion = (Get-ItemProperty $_).CurrentVersion
        Write-Debug "Current Java version is $CurrentVersion, based on $($_)"
        $VersionKey = Join-Path $_ $CurrentVersion
        $JavaHomeBasedPath = Join-Path (Get-ItemProperty $VersionKey).JavaHome $JavaExeSuffix
        Write-Debug "Testing for $JavaHomeBasedPath, based on $VersionKey\JavaHome"
        if (Test-Path $JavaHomeBasedPath) { $JavaHomeBasedPath }
    } |
    select -First 1

if ($JavaExePath -ne $null) {
    Write-Debug "Found $JavaExePath"
    return $JavaExePath
}

}

$path_java = Find-JavaExe
$java_param =  " -jar "
$path_prog = 
$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath('.\')
$program_name = "\ResizeProgram.jar "
$command = $path_java + $java_param + $path_prog + $program_name + """$p1"""
iex $command
```

it works fine and handles paths with spaces
but I have another problem when running it from comtextmenu of the folder, prompt appears saying:

- This program will not work on your computer; again.

In regedit I wrote simple:

- path.ps1 "%1"

Comment: ok problem solved in command value should be:
**powershell "& "E:\Projekty\Java\Resize_Program\out\artifacts\Resize_Program_jar\run.ps1""" "%1"**