# uninstalling java from command prompt

Tags: java

I have uninstalled all java  from everywhere  and in command prompt it shows:

```
C:\Users\admin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

I uninstall java from control panel but then also it shows in command prompt
[screen shot of control panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzWuv.png)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know what is installed in your system. There maybe multiple versions installed with different methods. If you see it in command line it has to be in the path. Search the path directories.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to find the path of the installed java that is showing up in your cmd.

Try running the below command on your windows machine to get the path of the installed java

```
for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

you can refer [How do I find where JDK is installed on my windows machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine) this thread for more details.

Once you find the path, try any of the steps mentioned here https://www.codejava.net/java-se/uninstall-jdk-from-windows for uninstalling.

Comment: you mean in command prompt I should type this right

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Yesss ! done java removed ,Thankyou

Comment: But that Java file is still there in control panel